# Method for finding the variable matrix of $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

As the title stated, what is the most efficient method for finding the variable matrix?

> For example, in the linear system $Ax = b$, given $$A =  
>          \begin{pmatrix}
>          1 & 1& 5 \\
>          2& 3& 4 \\
>          0& 1& -1\\
>          1 & 1& 2 \\
>          \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$b =  
>          \begin{pmatrix}
>          16 \\
>          13 \\
>          -4\\
>          7 \\
>          \end{pmatrix}$$ what would then be the variable matrix $x$?

For my attempt, i've thought of reducing $(A|b)$ into its reduced row-echelon form:

I've got the $I_{4}$ instead, which probably doesn't tell me much.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you think it tells you much? If you've reduced the equation to
$$I_{4\times 4} x = \tilde b$$
for some new right-hand side $\tilde b$, what is $x$?

Comment: Does it mean that $x = (0, 0, 0)$? However, apparently i've got the answer that $x = (2, -1, 3)$ as the solution to the linear system. How does one derive that variable matrix?